# Embedding website inside another

Tags: html, embedding

A customer asked to be able to call my web app from his domain for hiding my domain name.
I remembed that several years ago it was used to use an hidden iframe ... is there a more "modern" solution?

Comment: Not really. Not one that's really viable.

Answer (score 1):

The only better solution is to actually host the site on the domain that you want it to appear on.

He might want to consider setting his DNS to point a subdomain at your servers if you are unwilling to install the application on his.